# How make ASP.Net recompile page on changes?

Tags: asp.net, apache, firefox, caching, mono

I created an aspx page and viewed it in Firefox and Chrome and it worked correctly, running the C# code. But when I make changes to the page (including deleting everything and serving up a blank page), both browsers continue to show the original compiled aspx page!

It appears that ASP.Net (the web server) is not recompiling despite changes to the aspx file. **The only way to get it to recompile is to change web.config and then restart the web server!**

I even added the following code, but it still loads the original page:

```
<script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load
    Random rd = new Random();
    Response.AddHeader("ETag", rd.Next(1111111, 9999999).ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Expires = -1;
End Sub
</script>
```

**TEST I DID TO RULE OUT BROWSER CACHING:**

1. Created an aspx page and loaded it in firefox only *(not in chrome)*
2. Changed the aspx file
3. Loaded aspx again in firefox but got no changes
4. Loaded it *(for the first time ever)* in Chrome and it still showed the old version!

***Using Apache and Mono, not IIS***

Comment: How do you changes the files? Remote (FTP, file share) or locally where IIS runs? IIS version?

Comment: @Peter_Kiss I'm just changing the file directly in a text editor. I'm running the server in VirtualBox but using a shared folder to house the files (they do actually change on the server). I'm actually using Apache, not IIS, with Mono.

Comment: If you modifying files remotely the remote machine not always recognise the changes. I have noticed this in Windows infrastructure but i think it's existing on other type of systems.

Comment: @PeterKiss Thanks, I'll try changing it to a local file and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a Mono+Apache on Linux issue. It doesn't see changes to pages that have been compiled. The only workarounds are:

1. Restart Apache webserver (this causes it to see them as changed) - only takes about 2 seconds
2. Delete the temporary files in "/tmp/www-data-temp-aspnet-0/" (This can be a bit buggy so #1's a better choice)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your web application is a `Web Application` project or a `Web Site` project. If it was a Web Application, you will need to compile each time you change something, whereas web site projects allow changes to get reflected without compilation. Also, you can use `Ctrl+F5` in browsers to get a non-cached copy of pages. Hope his helps.

Read details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

Comment: I'm not creating it with Visual Studio. I just created a ".aspx" file in a text editor and put it into the folder. The only files in the website's folder are the aspx and cs files I created.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: It is browser's fault, and it is expected behavior by design. Force cache refresh in browsers (Ctrl-F5 in IE).

Correction: When it is Mono/Apache stack, not an IIS. Then manual restarts can be the only workaround. In IIS the stale effects are naturally cleared in between periods of inactivity, when server kills idle processes. In Mono, there may or may not be same cleaning schedule, so, the process lifecycle and configs are the first place to look at for fix.

The behavior of not recompiling is caused by complex identity of requested pages. Identity includes URL, timestamp and session. If you trying to refresh page without closing the browser, then ASP server will need to serve a stale copy of older compiled page, because server tries to maintain consistency of served page with existing session, viewstate, perhaps even client side scripts wich exist on client in between partial updates, etc. Also browsers are designed to comply to slowly changed internet pages with storing copies in cache and maintaining the age of copies to skip unnecessary network trips. Or else internet would be 10 times slower.

Other note: The most slow files to push through ASP server are css files.

Comment: Clear cache completely and restart browser. I'd still keep looking at browser before trying to fix server.

Comment: I did that. I also disabled the cache in firefox and cleared the cache and it didn't fix the issue. And the issue occurs in both Chrome and Firefox. And the reason I know that's not the issue? I created a page and loaded it in firefox only (not in chrome), then I changed it and tried loading it again in firefox but got no changes. Then I loaded it (for the first time ever - so definitely not in cache) in Chrome and it still showed the old version! So it's not the browsers.

Comment: Wait. You should mention that it is Apache and Mono in main question. Many could assume that the question is relevant to iis. Then it is server's fault. As usual, lesser products to be blamed for problems. In IIS this stale effects do not stay longer than 15-20 min. Because the process is killed automatically after some fixed time of inactivity